# How to do Serialization date from XML to C#.NET

Tags: c#, xml, date

```
<ENVELOPE>        
        <BODY>
          <IMPORTDATA>
           <REQUESTDATA>
            <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
             <VOUCHER REMOTEID="4b6b9384" VCHKEY="4b6b9384" VCHTYPE="Payment" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
              <DATE>20160102</DATE>
             </VOUCHER>
            </TALLYMESSAGE>
           </REQUESTDATA>
          </IMPORTDATA>
         </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

this is the xml file,Now I want to serialize date into .net as like 01/02/2016(dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy format)
I tried this two way

```
objCompanyVouchar.VOUCHER_DATE=XmlConvert.ToDateTime(node.SelectSingleNode("DATE").InnerText)
objCompanyVouchar.VOUCHER_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(node.SelectSingleNode("DATE").InnerText);
```

But it show the exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Do anyone knows how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing need to do with `XmlConvert` or required for `Convert` class.

Let's say you know the format is "yyyyMMdd", then what you need to do is:

```
var date= DateTime.ParseExact(node.SelectSingleNode("DATE").InnerText,"yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

objCompanyVouchar.VOUCHER_DATE= date; //If VOUCHER_DATE is DateTime 
//objCompanyVouchar.VOUCHER_DATE = date.ToString(); //If VOUCHER_DATE is String
```

| you can choose the format you want, read more at [ToString()](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjDitzRwPXQAhWMJZQKHY3IDm8QFggjMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fzdtaw1bw(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHUejA01dvIHKKw0vNLUWS2ZerYdQ&sig2=VuTr4ibZl8j3z-f2lG5nfA)

Comment: Hi Jacky,On the above XML partyledgername are more than one.How to find the  both partyledgername

Comment: Hi @anisprogrammer You can use `SelectNodes` : `var pnameNodes = node.SelectNodes("PARTYLEDGERNAME");` pnameNodes is a XmlNodeList with `pnameNodes[0].InnerText = "Standard Chartered Bank";` and `pnameNode[1].InnerText = "XYZ Ltd";`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace XMLTest1
{
    public class Test
    {
        public String value1;
        public String value2;
    }

    class listtest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
            XPathNavigator xNav = myXml.CreateNavigator();
            Test myTest = new Test() { value1 = "Value 1", value2 = "Value 2" };
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(myTest.GetType());
            using (var xs = xNav.AppendChild())
            {
                x.Serialize(xs, myTest);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(myXml.OuterXml);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var inportData = doc.Descendants("IMPORTDATA").Select(x => new {
                reportName = (string)x.Descendants("REPORTNAME").FirstOrDefault(),
                company = (string)x.Descendants("SVCURRENTCOMPANY").FirstOrDefault(),
                remoteID = (string)x.Descendants("VOUCHER").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("REMOTEID"),
                vchKey = (string)x.Descendants("VOUCHER").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("VCHKEY"),
                date = DateTime.ParseExact((string)x.Descendants("DATE").FirstOrDefault(), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                voucherName = (string)x.Descendants("VOUCHERTYPENAME").FirstOrDefault(),
                voucherNumber = (int)x.Descendants("VOUCHERNUMBER").FirstOrDefault(),
                ledgerName = (string)x.Descendants("PARTYLEDGERNAME").FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```